# ajax call that returns json file

Tags: php, json

im trying to figure out what the easiest way would be. i have a to do an api call for data i get a json file in return but im trying to parse the data to php so that my website would just pull from the database. do i have to create all the same fields that the api call is using for instance name gender age height. and then do i name it something else so i can call from my webpage. because in order to get a nfl player it gives me a 16 digit code and i want it just to be say tom brady

i have used javascript to pull the data but dont know what to do from there

```
"players": [{
        "name": "Kyle Rudolph",
        "jersey": "82",
        "last_name": "Rudolph",
        "first_name": "Kyle",
        "abbr_name": "K.Rudolph",
        "preferred_name": "Kyle",
        "birth_date": "1989-11-09",
        "weight": 265.0,
        "height": 78,
        "status": "A01",
        "id": "1059e9dc-97df-4643-9116-883a0573d8b1",
        "position": "TE",
        "birth_place": "Cincinnati, OH, USA",
        "high_school": "Elder (OH)",
        "college": "Notre Dame",
        "college_conf": "Independent",
        "rookie_year": 2011,
        "draft": {
            "year": 2011,
            "round": 2,
            "number": 43,
            "team": {
                "name": "Vikings",
                "market": "Minnesota",
                "alias": "MIN",
                "id": "33405046-04ee-4058-a950-d606f8c30852"
            }
        },
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Do you want to store data from an API in your own database?

Comment: Post your ajax and PHP codes, let's see what you are doing.

Comment: yes that way i can recall it for what i need instead of keep using the api

Comment: The question is not really clear, could you provide a more thorough description of what you're trying to achieve, possibly with an example and the code you have so far?

Comment: So store what you want to store and ignore the rest. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Only you can answer these questions john, specially based on the little info you give us, we can only make **guesses**

Comment: Regarding those _16 Character codes(UUID's)_ I am guessing a bit, but I would expect that they are used to identify teams or players uniquely. Other API's you may use therefore will likely use them as well. Remember names are a dangerous thing to identify people _or franchises come to that_ by, as what happens when you have 2 John Hancocks playing in the league

Comment: @RiggsFolly one of them is an impostor

Comment: @BeetleJuice In this case I think both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John, you don't have to use the same names.  Once your PHP receives data from the API, parse it into whatever names you want, ignore the values you don't need etc... For example, suppose the API gives you a first and last name, but in your database you only care about full name. As another example, if the API gives you player weight in pounds but you need it in kilograms:

```
$api_result = file_get_contents($url);
$api_data = json_decode($api_result);
$name = "$api_data->last, $api_data->first"
$weight = $api_data->weight * 0.454; //convert pounds to kg for storage
```

Now you can store `$name` and `$weight` in your DB as you like. When your website pulls data from your backend, the shape of the data produced by the API doesn't matter because you stored it in the shape that is most helpful to your application

Comment: last question i used javascript page to pull the api. i now have to create a php page to get the data from the javascript page correct

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    
 var global;
    $(function() {
  var api = "http://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/583";
  $.get( api,
function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    global = data;
          for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
   $("#result").append(global.aliases[x]+"<br>");
    }
    });
});

Comment: @johnhandcock If you intend to store results in your DB, then learn how to use PHP to pull from the API. The same PHP script that fetches the data will save it.  JavaScript is only involved when the webpage wants to get the info from *your* server.